# sql server: import operation won't copy full schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssms

I recall that the import tool in sql server 2000 would copy indexes, relationships, etc. 
In sql server 2005/2008 the import tool in SSMS will only create the tables, copy the data, but the keys, indexes, relationships are missing. I can find no option in the import wizard to enable this? What am I missing here? Is this not possible anymore for any good reason?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go for "Transfer SQL Server objects" in SSIS.

[Here's](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/transfer-sql-server-objects-task.aspx) a simple illustration to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Not simple enough, I cannot penetrate the jargon in the opening sentence. ssis is not available via ssms, but I know I have run it before. How do you run ssis? It's not in the start menu or in ssms.

Comment: Start Menu >> Microsoft SQL Server >> SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS). In BIDS . New >> Project >> Templates >> Integration Services Project

Answer (score 0):

Another choice is to use the [Database Publishing Wizard](http://sqlhost.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Database%20Publishing%20Wizard&referringTitle=Home).